# 'module' object has no attribute 'Twitter'

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to follow the example on page 5 of the book: Mining the Social Web, from O'Reilly. I am coming across the following error:

```
>>> import twitter
>>> twitter_api = twitter.Twitter(domain="api.twitter.com", api_version='1')
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Twitter'
```

What might be going on?

Comment: dir a `dir(twitter)` and see if `Twitter` shows up

Comment: no its not...I am wondering if the api changed and the book is outdated.....

Comment: If you are interested in working with twitter's api i'd recommend tweepy. It's very good and quite easy to use: https://github.com/joshthecoder/tweepy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the value of `twitter.__file__` (after you've imported twitter). My guess is either you somehow got a broken version of twitter, or you've created a file called twitter.py in the same directory you're running from that's blocking the installed module from loading.

If `twitter.__file__` looks good (points to where your installed modules should be instead of the local dir), try `easy_install -U twitter` to reinstall it.

Comment: Thx, exactly what was going on. Removed the egg and reinstalled and its working fine now.

Comment: @jason: So it was a bad egg and not a local file?

Comment: not sure, it was weird because the module worked but didn't have all the classes in it... not sure, but pulled it and then worked like a charm!

Comment: I had the same problem when I had installed both python-twitter and twitter libraries.

Answer (score 4):

Works for me. I installed `twitter` through `easy_install`, which installed the latest version (1.6.1). `dir(twitter)` also lists `Twitter` here.

You could remove the twitter package from site-packages and try reinstalling again.